# Functional programing with javascript: Extract the n-th paramter and send it to a function as paramter

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, underscore.js

Let's say I have an API, which offers me a function, that has to be augmented with two parameters: an "settings" object and a callback function, to wich 3 parameters will be sent.

As an example the request package in node.js:

```
var request = require("request");

request({
   uri: "http://www.something.com"
}, function(error, response, body) {
   doSth(body);
});
```

As you can see, the only thing I intend, is to extract the body of the response and process it further.

Is there any shorter solution for the task "extract one argument and send it to a function"?. Here are the approaches:

```
var arg2funct = 
function arg2funct(nr, funct) {
  return function() {
    funct(arguments[nr]);
   }
}

request({ uri: "http://www.something.com" }, arg2funct(2, doSth) );
```

---

Or with underscore:

```
__ = require("underscore");

var arg2funct = function(nr, funct, x, y, z) { funct(arguments[nr+2]); };
request({ uri: "http://www.something.com" }, __.partial(arg2funct, 2, doSth) );
```

The question now is: How can the function become more general? Because this one works only if the callback awaits 3 parameters (x, y, z).

And also: Is there maybe a better way to solve this with the underscore library? Or: do I maybe have to switch to another one.

Comment: bind:`request({uri: "http://www.something.com"}, doSth.bind(this,0,0));`

Comment: What generalization makes sense for your usecase? - If you have only one instance of this call to `request`, I would just write it as in your first code example. If you have this call or something similar more than once, I would generalize according to the common pattern of the use cases.

Comment: With ```var lift = function(f) { return function() { return f.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)) }}``` you could write it as ```request({uri: "http://www.something.com"}, lift(lift(doSth)));``` - but whether this or your ```arg2func``` or something else is a good solution depends on what exactly is the repeating pattern in your use case.

Comment: In ES6 you can write ```request({uri: "http://www.something.com"}, (error, response, body) => doSth(body))```

Comment: this looks like a real improvement!